# Prove that $\int\int_Df(x,y)dA \leq \int\int_D g(x,y)dA$ if $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in D$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f,g$ are integrable function on a Jordan set $D$ such that $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in D$. Prove that $\int\int_Df(x,y)dA \leq \int\int_D g(x,y)dA$

Here is what I got:

Assume that $f,g$ are integrable function on a Jordan set $D$ such that $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in D$.

Since $f(x,y) \leq g(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in D$, $g(x,y)-f(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $(x,y) \in D$

Since $f,g$ are integrable function on a Jordan set $D$ , they are bounded and

$$\int\int_D [g(x,y)-f(x,y)] \geq 0$$

$$\int\int_D [g(x,y)-f(x,y)]=\int\int_D [g(x,y)]- \int\int_D[f(x,y)] \geq 0$$

$$\int\int_D [g(x,y)] \geq \int\int_D[f(x,y)]$$

Please feel free to fix if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems pop out right away: first, the integral of a function $f$ is not given by the formula $$\int\int_Df(x,y)dA = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m(M_{f_i}-m_{f_i})(\Delta x_i \Delta y_j). $$ Second $f(x,y) \le g(x,y)$ does not imply $M_{f_i}-m_{f_i} \le M_{g_i}-m_{g_i}.$

Comment: if I understand correctly, the double integral of a function, is the sum of areas of the rectangle that cover the graph of the function, am I correct?

Comment: No. It is a *limit* of Riemann sums.

Comment: I fixed my argument, can you take a look and see if it's better please?